# Dúvida sobre preenchimento de Array em Java

Tags: java, array

Estou com dificuldades em resolver o seguinte exercício:

> - Crie uma classe com um método main;
> - Crie um array de int com 10 posições e o popule usando o for;
> - Imprima todos os valores do array e, para os valores pares, mostre o valor seguido da palavra "par"(use o operador % para saber quando é
>     par)

Primeiramente eu fiz assim, porém está dando erro de compilação:

```
public class MeuArray {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int[] MeuArray = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            if (MeuArray[i] % 2 == 0) {
         System.out.prinln("O vetor é par:", MeuArray[i]);
        } else {
            System.out.println("O vetor é impar:" MeuArray[i]);
        }

 }
 }
}
```

Mudei para esse código e as saídas estão mostrando o resultado 0:

```
public class MeuArray {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int[] MeuArray = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            if (MeuArray[i] % 2 == 0) {
         System.out.println(MeuArray[i]);
        } else {
            System.out.println(MeuArray[i]);
        }

 }
 }

}
```

Comment: E quando você popula o array? Percebeu que já está criando ele e exibindo sem popula-lo?

Comment: O código não está errado, você só esqueceu de fazer o que foi pedido no segundo item do exercicio, que é **popule usando for**

Comment: Sim, percebi, eu não sei como popula um array com for em java, sou iniciante.

Comment: O primeiro código não compila pq vc usou `prinln` ao invés de `println`, e o certo seria ter um `+` entre o texto e o valor: `"O vetor é impar:" + MeuArray[i]` ao invés de `"O vetor é impar:" MeuArray[i]` e `"O vetor é par:" + MeuArray[i]` ao invés de `"O vetor é par:", MeuArray[i]`. Já sobre o segundo código, faltou popular o array, conforme já comentado. Vc precisa fazer dois laços `for`, um para popular os valores, e outro para imprimí-los

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu segundo código não está errado, mas conforme mencionei nos comentários, você mal criou o array, e sem popula-lo, já está varrendo seus valores.

O resultado sempre é zero porque um array do tipo primitivo `int`, quando criado, já é preenchido com 0 como valor inicial em todas as posições.

Pra popular um array, a lógica é a mesma que você já está utilizando para varre-lo, crie um laço que vá da posicao 0 até a `tamanhodoarray-1` e atribua valores a cada posiçao, seria algo semelhante ao abaixo:

```
for(int i = 0; i < meuArray.length; i++){

    meuArray[i] = <valor que voce ira atribuir>;

}
```

Lembrando que se utilizar um valor literal para atribuir a posição do array, todas as posições serão iguais, o exercício nao fala em entrada do usuário, mas caso seja permitido usar, voce pode utilizar a classe Random para gerar números aleatórios.

Outro ponto lembrado pelo usuario [@hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) é a forma como você está concatenando valores dentro do `println()`, para concatenar strings em java, se utiliza do simbolo `+` e não `,` ou espaço, mesmo que tivesse feito a grafia do método de impressão corretamente, daria erro de compilação por este motivo.

A forma correta seria algo como abaixo:

```
System.out.println("isto é uma string literal" + variavelQualquer)
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigada pela ajuda!

Answer (score -1):

O que você deseja colocar no array? primeiramente o Array que você criou possui 10 posições, você pode preencher ele assim:

MeuArray[i] = i;

desta forma vc vai preencher a posição i, que no caso é de 0 a 9; com o próprio numero do i.

coloca esse comando embaixo do comando for, em cima do primeiro if e vê o que acontece.

Comment: Este não e o unico problema da pergunta. Sugiro que releia com calma para confirmar

Comment: Entendo, só quis resolver de forma basica preenchendo o array com o numero da propria posição, utilizando o resto ele ja descobre qual é  par e qual é impar.

Comment: Não me leve a mal, mas a solução que você deu ai não resolve o problema, so cria uma complexidade que o autor, como disse ser principiante, iria ficar mais com duvida ainda. Mas  se você acha que a resposta atende, tudo bem, não precisamos ficar debatendo isso. Foi só uma dica, a opção de escolher aceita-la ou não é sua mesmo.

Comment: Você acha que o que eu falei cria uma complexidade? Se ficou incomodado e incluiu minha resposta como não útil a opinião é sua. A minha intenção foi a de ajudar e acho que ficou claro o que fazer e porque.

Comment: Não fiquei incomodado Camilo, foi apenas uma opinião a respeito do que a resposta poderia ter para torná-la mais completa para o autor. Como eu disse anteriormente, não me leve a mal, foi apenas uma dica voltada a melhora do conteúdo do post, se você discorda, tudo bem, sem problemas, somos uma comunidade livre, discordar faz parte ;)

Comment: @Camilo agradeço pela sua solução, não achei complexa, ela também complementou a primeira que recebi. Por que pelo o que entendi do enunciado, era pra preencher os vetores automaticamente utilizando o for. Na primeira solução eu teria que atribuir os valores, com a sua os valores foram preenchidos automaticamente conforme a numeração do contador.